# Computer sometimes load grub not Windows bootloader

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

Sometimes my notebook loads grub instead of windows bootloader and I do not know why. Before I reinstalled Windows 7 32 bit I had ubuntu on it (windows installation). I have not installed another Linux after reinstallation. I assume that there are some leftover files from linux but I can not figure out where they are. Any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I found a hidden file called UIFWD with no extension on a C drive where windows is installed. If I open it with notepad the are lots of stuff like " ` ŽĂ1Űf;FDtf‰FDč* g&€bgf " but also readable text referring to GRUB4DOS. Still do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Windows, open an elevated Command Prompt and type `bcdboot C:\Windows`. Hit enter and wait for cmd to acknowledge it.

This will **not** delete GRUB, but rather set the Windows bootloader to load as default. Unless you want to delete GRUB too, this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to completely remove GRUB - if this is the case, I've had luck with EasyBCD. There should be a big button somewhere saying "Write Windows MBR".

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).